# Import fuctions not working on PyCharm and I can't figure out why from other questions, what may be going wrong?

Tags: import, pycharm

Title really does say it all. I'm pretty new to coding and I was going to make an alarm. I started off in IDLE and it was working perfectly fine for the most part. Switched over to PyCharm because it looked like more tutorials are done using it, and uh. I can't even get the 'import time' to work if I copy and paste it from the old script

Comment: it's hard to tell but have you configured an interpreter? Have you tried creating a new python project using the wizard?

Comment: @mx0 I don't think I have, and uh... the wizard?

Comment: New project wizard. File > new project > python. There you can set up python interpreter or virtual env.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Start by configuring an interpreter for the console, see [Working with Python console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/interactive-console.html#python-console) for instructions on how to get the console working. First step as mx0 said is creating a new project and going to the settings to configure the Python interpreter for the project.